# ConstraintLayout: Vertically align center of TextView to a position with offset

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I would like to create labels on some well known positions of a graphic. For this I have to align the **vertical center** of "Enable" TextView **exactly** at the first horizontal line of my graphic residing with 16dp offset below top of the ImageView.

[image: Enable TextView is top aligned]

The layout below aligns the top of TextView to the horizontal line, like in the screenshot, but that not leads to a solution. Unfortunatly I can't rely on a fixed height of the TextView in order to subtract from `android:layout_marginTop="16dp"`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/id_content_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_network"
            android:layout_width="96dp"
            android:layout_height="192dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/network_6x1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id_enable"
            style="@style/Widget.AppTheme.Helper"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Enable"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/image_network"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/image_network"
            />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id_out"
            style="@style/Widget.AppTheme.Helper"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:text="Out"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/image_network"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/image_network"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/image_network"
            />
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

If I would add `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/image_network"` to the TextView, both horizontal edges become aligned to the top of the ImageView, it effects in aligning its vertical center to the top of the ImageView, but now it ignores `android:layout_marginTop="16dp"`

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id_enable"
        style="@style/Widget.AppTheme.Helper"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Enable"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/image_network"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/image_network"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/image_network"
        />
```

The "Out" TextView is perfectly vertical centered to the single line on the right side, but this is only randomly because the line is just in the vertical center of the graphic.

The only workaround I have found so far is to use an additional empty helper View with a `layout_height="16dp"`, aligning it Top_toTopOf of the ImageView and now align both horizontal edges of the TextView to the bottom of the helper View.

```
    <View
        android:id="@+id/id_enable_dummy"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/image_network"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/image_network"
        />
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id_enable"
        style="@style/Widget.AppTheme.Helper"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="Enable"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/image_network"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/id_enable_dummy"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/id_enable_dummy"
        />
```

But this will need an additionally View ressource for each label TextView which seems to be to much overhead. Will this really be neccessary or does anybody knows a better solution?

Besides: If I would like to align the labels on their baseline instead of their vertical center, I observe basically the same, `android:layout_marginTop="16dp"` does not work in combination.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I have understood your problem properly, but maybe this will help you: With these 3 lines the TextView is placed at e.g. 15% of the height of the ImageView:

```
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.15"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/image_network"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/image_network"
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your idea. I've tried, but this does not place it exactly regarding the vertical center of the TextView, except with the value "0.5", which places it exactly in the mid of ImageView. The first line has offset 16dp at an ImageView  height of 192dp, for this I calculate the value 16/192=0,083. I don't know how Vertical_bias calculate the position, but with this value the top of EditView is nearly placed to the line, but not its vertical center.

Comment: using `android:layout_marginTop="-160dp"` instead seems to set the position right. The needed Value can be calculated by `-ImageHeight + 2*offset = -192+2*16 = -160`. This formula works with all other lines, beeing at `offset=16+32*iLine`. But I don't know, why. And documentation says, margins should be a positive value ...